# How to install MYSQL JDBC DRIVER in OpenShift without pom.xml file?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ant, openshift

I am trying to deploy OpenGTS_2.6.0 on OpenShift online where I have Tomcat7 MySQL-5.5 and Ant Cartridge 0.1.So I don't know how to install the mysql jdbc driver into tomcat and java directory and my project is ant based not a maven based project.

```
>Version: 2.6.0
[WARN_|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:806] JDBC driver class not found: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
[WARN_|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:806] JDBC driver class not found: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
[WARN_|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:806] JDBC driver class not found: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:827] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:832] Install the JDBC jar file in one of the following directories:
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:834]  > /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91/jre/lib/ext
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:834]  > /usr/java/packages/lib/ext
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:843] (NOTE: The installed jar file permissions must also be world-readable)
[ERROR|DBProvider.loadJDBCDriver:844] -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:940] SQLException message: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:941] ==> SQLException: DB create error [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/]
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:941] Message:   No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:941] SQLState:  08001
[ERROR|DBAdmin.execCommands:941] ErrorCode: 0
[DBAdmin.execCommands:941] java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.getConnection(DBConnection.java:662)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:772)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.createStatement(DBConnection.java:760)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection._executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:1014)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:969)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBConnection.executeUpdate(DBConnection.java:950)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBProvider.createDatabase(DBProvider.java:1699)
        at org.opengts.dbtools.DBAdmin.execCommands(DBAdmin.java:929)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig._main(DBConfig.java:1833)
        at org.opengts.db.DBConfig.main(DBConfig.java:1948)
```

Comment: There is an instruction in the message you copy/pasted (although putting it into `lib/ext` is actually bad advice and will no longer work in newer (future) Java versions).

Comment: Further to comment from @Mark re: `lib/ext`, more details [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under).

Comment: Thanks Mark Rotteveel and Gord Thompson.but how can I access to jdbc driver for opengts?

Comment: Normally you would deploy the JAR file(s) for the JDBC driver (and its dependencies, if any) into the `/WEB-INF/lib/` folder of your webapp on the Tomcat server.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.So this process Can I use locally on my directory and then git add,git commit,git push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Straight from the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#MySQL_DBCP_Example):

> Before you proceed, don't forget to copy the JDBC Driver's jar into
>   $CATALINA_HOME/lib.

Comment: Thank you very much Lolo.But I think that in openshift we can't copy this jar file to $CATALINA_HOME/lib.Am I right?